# convert date and time string from one format to another

Tags: php

I have a date and time string with this date

```
$old_date = 'Oct 2 10:07:07 2015 GMT';
```

I would like to convert it to this format

> Fri, 02 Oct 2015 10:07:07 +0000

I've tried this but it didn't work:

```
$old_timestamp = strtotime($old_date);
$new_Date = date('jS F Y H:i A T O', filemtime($old_timestamp));
```

Comment: Hi Rizier, i tried a solution from that other link but it didnt work for me which is why i am opening a new thread for assistance

Comment: Read the **entire** dupe and read it **carefully**. Your solution is in there.

Comment: ok cool.. removing filemtime() seemed to work